# How to construct non-abelian functions?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, finite-groups, fourier-transform

I have found some functions $t_g, g \in G$ for cyclic groups $G=C_n$ which seem to satisfy the following convolution identity:

$$t_g(x+y) = \sum_{h \in G} t_{gh^{-1}}(x) t_h(y)$$

Example of such functions are given in this question:
[Connection between cyclic group and exponential function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227161/connection-between-cyclic-group-and-exponential-function)

and a possible generalization to arbitrary finite groups was given in this answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/412397/165920

However in the answer only consequences of the convolution identity are shown but it is not shown how to construct such functions.

So my question is:
**Given the symmetric group $G = S_3$. Is it possible to construct functions $t_g$ which satisfy the convolution identity above?**

I have added the tag for odes since the functions given as examples satisfy:

$$t^{'''}_{k}(x) = t_{k}(x), k=0,1,2$$

Comment: What is the domain and range of these functions?

Comment: @Wojowu: $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/412397/165920