# Is $\sum_{\rho \text{ irred. }} \deg(\rho) \chi_{\rho}(g)=0$ for every group element $1 \neq g \in G$ of the finite group $G$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Is $\sum_{\rho \text{ irred. }} \deg(\rho) \chi_{\rho}(g)=0$ for every froup element $1\neq g \in G$ of the finite group $G$?

I have searched for but not found a proof to this. Probably it is not so difficult, but has as application that:

$$\det(T_G) = 1$$

where $T_G = (t_{gh^{-1}})_{g,h \in G}$ is the group matrix defined for the functions defined in this [answer:](https://mathoverflow.net/a/412397/165920)

$$\widehat{t_{x}}(\rho) := \mathbf{1}_{d_{\rho}} \exp( \frac{1}{d_{\rho}} \sum_{s \in S}\chi_{\rho}(s) x_s )$$

where $S$ (with $1 \notin S$) generates the finite group $\left< S \right > = G$.

From this we get, since we know by Frobenius, the factorization of the group determinant :

$$\det(T_G) = \prod_{\rho \text{ irred.}} \det( \sum_{g \in G} t_g(x) \rho(g) )^{d_{\rho}} = \prod_{\rho \text{ irred.}} \det( \widehat{t_x}(\rho))^{d_{\rho}} = \prod_{\rho \text{ irred.}} \det( \mathbf{1}_{\rho} \exp \left ( \frac{1}{d_{\rho}}  \sum_{s \in S} \chi_{\rho}(s) x_s \right ) )^{d_{\rho}} $$
$$= \prod_{\rho \text{ irred. }} \exp( \sum_{s \in S} \chi_{\rho}(s) x_s)^{\deg(\rho)}$$
$$ =\exp\left( \sum_{\rho \text{ irred.}} \deg(\rho) \sum_{s\in S} \chi_{\rho}(s) x_s \right)$$

and which is equal to:

$$=\exp(\sum_{s \in S} x_s \cdot \left ( \sum_{\rho} \deg(\rho) \chi_{\rho}(s) \right ) )  =^? \exp(0)=1$$

So if the question answers positive, then the determinant should be equal to $1$ .

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It doesn't hold for the trivial group, where the sum equals 1.

Comment: For general groups this fails if g is the identity.

Comment: Could you explain why you started off wanting to prove a certain identity, claiming it would help you with an argument in the linked answer, and have now changed the target? Either the original identity was what you needed for the linked answer or it wasn't

Comment: Thank your for your pointer. There was a small "error" in the definition of the Fourier transform, which made the addition theorem still work, but det≠1. Now I have corrected it and it should be det=1. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion holds with deg$(\rho)^2$ replaced with deg$(\rho)$.
You also need the extra requirement that the group element $g$ is non-trivial.
Then the Plancherel Theorem implies that the right hand side equals the trace of the left translation $L_g$ on $\ell^2(G)$. Then you compute this trace as
$$
\mathrm{tr}(L_g)=\sum_{y\in G}\langle L_g\delta_y,\delta_y\rangle=\sum_{y\in G}\langle \delta_{gy},\delta_y\rangle=0.
$$

Comment: thanks for your insight

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by Plancherel theorem?

Comment: The regular character is the sum of $deg(\rho)\chi_{\rho}$ without the square. So what you want is true without the square but false with the square as @GeoffRobinson explained

Comment: I realised that and already edited my solution accordingly.

Comment: In light of the error, I don't really think this counts as a "solution". This is a bit like saying "the value of six times nine is 42 (if you replace the nine by seven)"

Comment: Since @GeoffRobinson's comment is no longer here it said the desired result is false for the symmetric group on 3 letters where g has order 3.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your answer. Can you please relate to the notation used in the question?

Comment: Now that you replaced deg^2 by deg this is just the standard statement that  an irreducible representation appears with multiplicity equal to its degree in the regular representation and so your sum is computing the character of the regular representation which is 0 on all nonidentity elements and |G| on the identity

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: thanks for the clarification