# Similarity in Navier-Stokes equation and convolution in finite abelian groups?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, finite-groups, fourier-transform, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, $X = (x_g)_{g \in G}$ be a vector of variables.

Set for $g \in G$:
$$\tau_g(X) := \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{\rho \text{ irred. }} \chi_{\rho}(-g) \exp(\sum_{s \in G} \chi_{\rho}(s)x_s)$$

Then we have:

$$\frac{\partial \tau_g(X)}{\partial x_h} = \tau_{g-h}(X)$$

Now we can write:

$$\sum_{g \in G} \tau_g(X) \frac{\partial \tau_h(X)}{\partial x_g} = \sum_{g\in G} \tau_g(X) \tau_{h-g}(X) =^! \tau_{h}(X+X) = \tau_h(2X)$$

(where $!$ means: The equality follows similar to the answer given here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/412397/165920
Hence this last equation might be interpreted as a convolution identity of finite abelian groups.)

Notice the similarity in the Navier-Stokes equation, if we write:

$$\sum_{g \in G} u_g(X) \frac{\partial u_h(X)}{\partial x_g}$$
instead of

$$\sum_{j=1}^3 u_j(X) \frac{\partial u_i(X)}{\partial x_j}$$

**My question is if this point of view brings something new to the problem of Navier-Stokes, if it is not asked too much?**

Happy New Year!

**Edit**:
I want to make a more concrete question by assuming that for all $i=1,2,3$, and for all $X = (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T,t$ we have the additional equation in Navier-Stokes, which is a weak form of the $=^!$ equation above:

$$u_i(t,2X) = \sum_{j=1}^3 u_j(t,X) \frac{\partial u_i(t,X)}{\partial x_j}$$

**My modified question is, if this leads to a contradiction or if it brings something new to the problem?**

Comment: You say that the "!" indicates that the equality follows similarly to the answer you link, but, in the comments to that answer, you [say](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227161/connection-between-cyclic-group-and-exponential-function/412397#comment1056875_412397) that "!" means "should equal".  If it means (as you also allow) "is equal to", then how does it differ from a bare "="?

Comment: @LSpice: There is no difference, just a highlighting for the eyes.

Comment: I believe this is a purely superficial similarity. The formula from the NS-equation is summing an index over three values, and there is no algebraic structure on the indexing set.